# set 3 div containers in the middle

Tags: html, css

I created now 3 Div container's. The width of each container is 300px + 2*4px for each border (right & left). The div containers are in a section and the width of the section is 1200px. And the result is now 92px space between each container. (1200px - (308px*3))/3 = 92px. But if i set a margin-left of 92px the space isnt correct and the containers arent in the middle of the section. Here is [myPage](http://skeptar.bplaced.net/Homepage/) and the
Code:

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

section{
    width: 1200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #00ff00;
    overflow: hidden;
}


.divbox{
    height: 300px;
    width: 250px;
    border: 4px dashed black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 92px;
}

.divbox:after{
    float: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Startseite</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>
            <article>
                <div class="divbox">
                    content
                </div>
                <div class="divbox">
                    content
                </div>
                <div class="divbox">
                    content
                </div>
            </article>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you want all 3 divs next to each other but in the middle of the section? I dont understand what you're trying to achieve

Comment: What happens in my screen width is under 1200px? Generally, fixed-width isn't the greatest approach.

Comment: in accordance with @TimLewis observation, my solution below is responsive (works for variable screen width)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your math is off. For one your width is `250px` not `300px`. And you're dividing by 3 when there is 4 spaces that need to be treated evenly. The difference between all spaces comes to 106.5 (round down):

[image]

```
.divbox{
    height: 300px;
    width: 250px;
    border: 4px dashed black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 106px;
}
```

[**EXAMPLE 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/9j6uwyes/)

But instead of using floats and margin to center these a better option to always assure that they are centered is to use `display: inline-block` and then set `text-align: center` on the parent `section`:

```
section{
    width: 1200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #00ff00;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center; //add
}


.divbox{
    display: inline-block; //add instead of float
    height: 300px;
    width: 250px;
    border: 4px dashed black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 0 50px;
}
```

[**EXAMPLE 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/9j6uwyes/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :) you helped me a lot! But if i set display:inline-block; i have a small space between the divs how can i delete the space's?

Comment: @Skeptar I meant if you werent concered with equal spacing. If you want equal space use example 1. If you dont care if the spaces on the sides are the same as the spaces inbetween, use example 2. Does that make sense?

Comment: One more question... What is the margin: 0 50px doing? I know it make margin-right & margin-left : 50px, but why 50px?

Answer (score 2):

something like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/124/

This code is responsive (will always stay in the middle of the screen even if you change the width of the screen)

```
<div class="layout">
    <div class="centre">
        <div class="divbox">
            content
        </div>
        <div class="divbox">
            content
        </div>
        <div class="divbox">
            content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

div.layout
{
  text-align: center;
}
div.centre
{
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

EDIT: added margins for the space in the middle

```
margin-left:20px;
margin-right:20px;
```

Comment: Only thing I *could* complain about is there being no space between the 3.

Comment: @TimLewis lol i knew someone was gonna comment on that lol but fair enough haha, edited with margins

Comment: I'll give yours a +1 for adhering to responsive design principals (as much as you can without using a framework) :P